# Android Google Maps Marker Icon Animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, marker

What I want is to animate the marker icon when I add the marker on the map. I'm using a custom icon and want to make a "pop-out" animation. Exactly like a scale animation, starting from lets say 0.2 to 1.0. That is easily done on a view, but the markers are not views, so does anyone have a good idea how to do that, besides setting the icon like 10 times during 1 second with different sizes?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Besides the option you already point out yourself, you could attempt to 'fake' the effect by positioning a (marker) view on top of the map view at screen location where the marker is supposed to end up. That view can easily be animated, and then upon completion you add the actual marker to the map (or add it and hide it initially and make it visible afterwards). The most difficult part would probably be how to deal with the user interacting with the map while one or more animations are happening. Also, not sure how performant or 'nice' the result will be, but I'll leave that up to you.